# How to get Windows Storage Spaces warning message

Tags: windows, hard-drive, storage-spaces

In what must be one of the stranges UX decisions ever, Windows tells me that one of my physical drives in a Storage Pool has a warning - but that's it. Bad S.M.A.R.T. values ? Unstable read rates ? High error rate ? Nobody knows, and Windows does not seem inclined to tell me. Surely that information must be available somewhere, any hints ?

Comment: Maybe more information is available in some Event Viewer log.

Comment: It's not terribly easy for a layman to tell, but it doesn't seem like anything in there is relevant. The only HDD/FS-relevant entries I see there are "Volume L: (\Device\HarddiskVolume11) is healthy.  No action is needed."

Comment: Have you run Speccy and checked the SMART flags on your drive?

Comment: I used Crystal Disk to read the SMART values, nothing unusual.